# Ratio of sides in a triangle vs ratio of angles?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Given a triangle with the ratio of sides being $X: Y : Z$, is it true that the ratio of angles is also $X: Y: Z$?  Could I see a proof of this?  Thanks

Comment: It is true if the triangle is equilateral.

Answer (score 9):

This is false. The sides and angles are related by the [*law of sines*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines): $$\frac{a}{\sin A}=\frac{b}{\sin B}=\frac{c}{\sin C}$$

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not true. Consider a 45-45-90 right triangle:

[image]

([image from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_right_triangles#45.E2.80.9345.E2.80.9390_triangle))

The sides are in the ratio $1:1:\sqrt{2}$, while the angles are in the ratio $1:1:2$.